# How to get the content inside the link that is clicked jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a couple of links that run the same function when they are clicked. But I need the text they contain as a variable in jQuery.

`var myVariable = content inside link`

I'm actually using this function that the link activates

```
function updateStatus() {
    var link_text = linktext_here;

    jQuery.post("/to/my/php/file/mylist.php", {firstParam : link_text}, function(data) {
        //this is your response data from serv
        console.log(data);

    });
    return false;
}
```

My links:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" 
   onclick="updateStatus(); class="statusWatching">Watching</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" 
   onclick="updateStatus(); class="statusWatching">On hold</a>
```

As you can see, I have multiple links that run the same function, now I just want to make sure that whichever link they click, that's the value of the text that goes to the `var link_text`

I am not using a click function so I am not sure if the current answers would work.

Comment: You want the text value of the link or the href or something else..? More specific please.

Comment: you're probably looking for `$(this)` inside the context of the `.click()` function.

Comment: I want the text value in the middle of `<a href="">thistext</a>`

Answer (score 1):

It's quite quick to do using jquery's [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function, and their [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)*

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="statusWatching">Watching</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="statusWatching">On hold</a>
```

** include this JS at the end of your page in `<script>` tags before the `</body>`**

```
$('.statusWatching').on('click', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var link_text = $(this).text();

    jQuery.post("/to/my/php/file/mylist.php", {firstParam : anime_id}, function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

*you want to have more than one on the page, so use the class attribute on the links to bind the function to the links, rather than id which should be only be set on one element on the page.

Comment: e.preventDefault() might be necessary too, depending on what asker is attempting to do after getting the text.

Comment: I've updated my question to explain my situation a little better.

Comment: my answer above would work with very few changes.. will try to update it for you

Comment: @user27899 updated above, though be aware that you're not setting `anime_id` anywhere in this..

Comment: This works out fine, although, I have to click twice for this to work properly. In my javascript console, nothing shows up when I click it the first time, when I click it again it shows the number 2 beside it's output, signifying that it has outputted it twice. However, it only outputs something when I click it twice.

Comment: I would suggest that that has something to do with the ajax query.  try commenting it out or adding `console.log(link_text)` before it to see when the click is made.. if you still have problems, it's best to raise a separate question here, so that the questions and answers remain as focused as possible.

Answer (score 1):

In example

```
<a href="http://www.link.com" class="mylink" >click here</a>
```

If you wanna get a hyperlink of a tag you can use

```
var link = $(".mylink").attr("href"); //to http://www.link.com
```

But if you wanna get the text of a tag you can do

```
var linkText = $(".mylink").text(); //to click here
```

Edited...

with your example

```
function updateStatus() {

     var element = event.target || event.srcElement || event.toElement;
     var link_text = element.innerText;

     jQuery.post("/to/my/php/file/mylist.php", {firstParam : link_text}, function(data) {
        //this is your response data from serv
        console.log(data);

     });

     return false;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question to explain my situation a little better.

Answer (score 0):

That's an easy one

`var txt = $(this).text(); //assuming your are handling this within a click event`

Answer (score -2):

You can assign text using `.text()`, for example:

```
$("a:first").text('your text here');
```

or

```
$("#a_id").text('your text here');
```

Comment: The OP wants to _get_ the text, not _set_ the text